# parent UIView is not showing but the subviews are showing i nswift

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout, constraints

this is the code I wrote

```
    let topViewa = UIView()
    topViewa.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(topViewa)
    topViewa.backgroundColor = .white
    topViewa.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 300).isActive = true
    topViewa.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    topViewa.frame.size =  CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: 44)
    let fw = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    fw.backgroundColor = .red
    topViewa.addSubview(fw)
```

with screenWidth being the width of the screen.

and when I run this, this is what I get

[image]

Why am I not getting the parent UIView with white background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I not getting the parent UIView with white background?

Because the white view has no size.

The line

```
topViewa.frame.size =  CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: 44)
```

...has no effect. You have elected to use *constraints* to position and size this view. Now you must fulfill that contract, giving it both position and size through constraints alone. You have not provided any height or width constraints (or alternatively, bottom or trailing constraints), so the view has zero size and you see nothing.

The red subview, meanwhile, remains visible, because the white superview's `clipsToBounds` is `false`. If it were `true`, you wouldn't see the red subview either.

Comment: is topViewa.frame.size =  CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: 44) not enough for givinng size? what do I need to do to add size then?

Comment: You can't use `frame` and `size`. You've declared that you are using _constraints_. You must provide height and width _constraints_, or bottom and trailing _constraints_.